# How to place player objects on a board in non adjacent cells?

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, object

I have the following code where up to 4 players can participate. The number of players (2-4) and the weapons are randomly placed on the board. However I'm trying to figure out a pattern where each player will be at least 1 box distanced from one another. Up to this point all players and weapons are placed on the board without any item overwriting another.

```js
var question = prompt('how many players');
var numOfPlayers = parseInt(question);

  class Game {
  constructor(row,col){
    this.gameBoard=[];
    for (var i=0; i<row; i++){
      this.gameBoard[i] = []; // init this.gameBoard[i]
      for (var y=0; y<col; y++){
        this.gameBoard[i][y]=0;
      }
    }
  }
}

class Player {
  constructor(id,location){
    this.health=100;
    this.damage=0;
    this.id=id;
    this.location=location;
  }
}

class Weapon {
  constructor(name,damage,location){
  this.name=name;
  this.damage=damage;
  this.location=location;
  }
}

var positions =[];
  for (var x=0; x<6; x++){
    for (var y=0; y<6; y++){
      positions.push({x,y});
    }
  }


var game = new Game(6,6);

var weaponCreation =function(weaponName,dmg){
    var weaponPosition =Math.floor(Math.random()*positions.length);
    var weaponName = new Weapon(weaponName,dmg,positions[weaponPosition]);
    positions.splice(weaponPosition,1);
    game.gameBoard[weaponName.location.y][weaponName.location.x] =weaponName;
}
weaponCreation('hammer',8);
weaponCreation('sword',10);
weaponCreation('knife',6);
weaponCreation('box-cutter',4);

// Placing players on the gameBoard //
let player =[];
for (var i=0; i <numOfPlayers; i++ ){
  var randomPosPlayer = Math.floor(Math.random()*positions.length);
  player.push(new Player(i, positions[randomPosPlayer]));
  positions.splice(randomPosPlayer, 1); // positions.lengths is decreased by 1 and thus the randomPosPlayer number will also in the next iteration
  game.gameBoard[player[i].location.y][player[i].location.x] =player[i];








}

// Placing players on the gameBoard - END //


console.log(game);
```

Comment: Please post your code directly into your question inside of a "code snippet" rather than posting a link to a 3rd party site as those links can die over time.

Comment: I can see the code under the question, how else should I be doing it  ?

Comment: When you are creating your question, there is a toolbar available for you to implement various formatting. The 7th button is for inserting a "code snippet" and it gives you an environment to enter HTML, CSS and JavaScript into that allows for us to be able to run it right here.